# Как сериализовать словарь в XML?

Tags: c#, xml

Класс, содержащий словарь

```
public class Something
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Thing { get; set; }
}
```

не сериализуется, выкидывая исключение в момент создания экземпляра класса XmlSerializer.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Something));
```

Как обойти это ограничение?

Answer (score 2):

Как выяснилось встроенными средствами словарь не сериализуется. Либо надо самому писать код сериализации, [реализуя интерфейс IXmlSerializable](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx). Либо отказываться от словаря, что я и сделал.

```
public class Something
{
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Thing { get; set; }
}
```

Добавляем элементы как

```
thing.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value));
```

Удаляем как

```
thing.Remove(thing.First(item => item.Key.Equals(key)));
```

Answer (score -1):

Давно уже не занимался сериализацией тоже была такая же проблема. Помоему должно быть ref или out перед typeof, если мне память не изменяет.